# extract blocks of columns (as seperated subarrays) indicated by 1D binary array

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, boolean

Based on a 1D binary mask, for example, `np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0])`, I would like to extract the columns of another array, indicated by the 1's in the binary mask, as as sub-arrays/separate blocks, like `[9, 3.5, 7]) and [2.8, 9.1]` (I am just making up the numbers to illustrate the point).

So far what I have (again just as a demo to illustrate what my goal is, not the data where this operation will be performed):

```
arr = torch.from_numpy(np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]))
split_idx = torch.where(torch.diff(arr) == 1)[0]+1
torch.tensor_split(arr, split_idx.tolist())
```

The output is:

```
(tensor([0, 0, 0]),
 tensor([1, 1, 1]),
 tensor([0, 0]),
 tensor([1, 1]),
 tensor([0]))
```

What I would like to have in the end is:

```
(tensor([1, 1, 1]),
 tensor([1, 1]))
```

Do you know how to implement it, preferably in pytorch, but numpy functions are also fine. A million thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct your tensor of slice indices with your approach. Only thing is you were missing the indices for the position of the end of each slice. You can do something like:

```
>>> slices = arr.diff().abs().nonzero().flatten()+1
tensor([ 3,  6,  8, 10])
```

Then apply [`tensor_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor_split.html) and slice to only keep every other element:

```
 >>> torch.tensor_split(arr, slices)[1::2]
 (tensor([1, 1, 1]), tensor([1, 1]))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the '[1::2]' hint! It just occurred to me if the binary mask does not start with 0's but 1's (e.g. [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]). The above method would extract the 0's. I could of course first check if it starts with 1 or 0 and act accordingly. But would you have a more efficient way of extracting the blocks of 1's?

Comment: In this case, your best bet is to append a single `0` at the beginning of the tensor such that the method works whatever the value of the starting block. You can do so by defining `arr_ = torch.cat([torch.zeros(1), arr])`, then applying the above method on `arr_`.